# Could not find the ttyUSB0 port on my Ubuntu Box saying NoSuchPortException

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, tty, modbus

I am new user for Ubuntu/Linux,and I am trying to connect to device to get serialized data,

with following params :

```
<bean id="serialParameters" class="net.wimpi.modbus.util.SerialParameters">
    <property name="baudRate" value="115200"/>
    <property name="portName" value="/dev/ttyUSB06"/>

    <property name="databits" value="8"/>
    <property name="stopbits" value="1"/>
    <property name="parity">
        <util:constant static-field="gnu.io.SerialPort.PARITY_NONE"/>
    </property>
    <property name="encoding">
        <util:constant static-field="net.wimpi.modbus.Modbus.SERIAL_ENCODING_RTU"/>
    </property>
    <property name="echo" value="false"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="200"/>
</bean>
```

I am getting this issue :

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception
    at net.wimpi.modbus.net.SerialConnection.open(SerialConnection.java:91)
    at net.wimpi.modbus.facade.ModbusSerialMaster.connect(ModbusSerialMaster.java:101)
    at com.example.MyModbusSerialMaster.connect(MyModbusSerialMaster.java:20)
```

And MyModbusSerialMaster.java is with line 20 (***super.connect();***):

```
public class MyModbusSerialMaster
        extends ModbusSerialMaster {
    public MyModbusSerialMaster(SerialParameters param) {
        super(param);
    }

    public void connect() throws Exception {
//        System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyUSB0"); //or oher ACMx
        ***super.connect();***
        try {
            Field f = ModbusSerialMaster.class.getDeclaredField("m_Transaction");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            ((ModbusSerialTransaction) f.get(this)).setRetries(0);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My Ubuntu Box confgig are :

Device : Inspiron-3542 (N series)
Ubuntu : 15.10
OS type : 64-bit

I have also gone through all suggestions given on SO like.

running cmd  : **ls /sys/class/tty/**

giving response :

> console  tty15   tty24  tty33  tty42  tty51  tty60      ttyS10  ttyS2   ttyS29
>   ptmx     tty16  tty25  tty34  tty43  tty52  tty61      ttyS11  ttyS20  ttyS3
>   tty  tty17  tty26  tty35  tty44  tty53  tty62      ttyS12  ttyS21  ttyS30
>   tty0     tty18  tty27  tty36  tty45  tty54  tty63      ttyS13  ttyS22  ttyS31
>   tty1     tty19  tty28  tty37  tty46  tty55  tty7       ttyS14  ttyS23  ttyS4
>   tty10    tty2   tty29  tty38  tty47  tty56  tty8       ttyS15  ttyS24  ttyS5
>   tty11    tty20  tty3   tty39  tty48  tty57  tty9       ttyS16  ttyS25  ttyS6
>   tty12    tty21  tty30  tty4   tty49  tty58  ttyprintk  ttyS17  ttyS26  ttyS7
>   tty13    tty22  tty31  tty40  tty5   tty59  ttyS0      ttyS18  ttyS27  ttyS8
>   tty14    tty23  tty32  tty41  tty50  tty6   ttyS1      ttyS19  ttyS28  ttyS9

Here ttyUSB0 is not present in output.
Current User is also in group of **dialout**.

Comment: I take it you use an USB to serial adapter. Did you try running 'lsusb' ?

Comment: @forevergenin this gives device info but at what port its connected ? can we find this also ?

Comment: yes. Check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81754/how-can-i-match-a-ttyusbx-device-to-a-usb-serial-device